# Can't use scrollbar with particles.js set at fixed position

Tags: wordpress, particles.js

We have particles.js loaded and cannot use the scrollbar on wordpress website. We need this to work with full height and full width. Please see html code below in link.
[Our html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iIEw.png)" : website link: http://www.tcnarch.co.za/about

We have tried disabling plugins and checked dev tools for errors and there are none. Have also tried overflow-x: auto and also removed the height: 100% atribute from css but to no avail. Please help we have tried everything to our knowledge. Thank you

```
#particles-js {
position:fixed;
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
}

#particles-js canvas {
display: block;
vertical-align: bottom;
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: opacity .8s ease, -webkit-transform 1.4s ease;
transition: opacity .8s ease, transform 1.4s ease
}
```

Comment: Have you found the answer? I've been facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem has been resolved. Fixed this by adding right: 10px suppose it's not the ideal solution but the scrollbar now works also what might help others in future is setting pointer events to all.

Comment: Use the wordpress plugin instead of hardcoding the particle.js library in your code, it will be more flexible.